# How to write a spock testcase for a method which calls other methods inside

Tags: testcase, spock

Say i have a method which populate some data to a list and it internally calls one more method(which i'm testing independently) and that populate some data to the list. Here what is the best way of testing?

How to test the outer Method? Should I check for the data's from inner Method also, else it is ok to test only the data's populated by outer method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the following class under test:

`class MyTestClass {
    int getAPlusB() { return getA() + getB() }
    int getA() { return 1 }
    int getB() { return 2 }
}`

I can write the following spock test to check that the arithmetic is correct, but also that `getA()` and `getB()` are actually called by `getAPlusB()`:

```
def "test using all methods"() { 
    given: MyTestClass thing = Spy(MyTestClass)
    when:  def answer = thing.getAPlusB()
    then:  1 * thing.getA()
           1 * thing.getB()
           answer == 3
}
```

So far this is running all the code on all 3 methods - getA and getB are verified as being called but the code in those methods are actually being executed. In your case, you are testing the inner methods seperately, and perhapse you do not want to call them at all during this test. By using the spock spy, you can instantiate a real instance of the class under test, but with the option of stubbing particular methods which you want to specify the value returned by:

```
def "test which stubs getA and getB"() {
   given: MyTestClass thing = Spy(MyTestClass)
   when:  def answer = thing.getAPlusB()
   then:  1 * thing.getA() >> 5
          1 * thing.getB() >> 2
          answer == 7
}
```